# set height to jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using jquery ui accordion.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active : 'none',
        autoHeight: false,
         navigation: true
        });
  });
```

and using CSS

```
#accordion
{
    width:70%;
    height:400px;
    padding-top:80px;
    padding-left:100px;
}
```

But the content of my first accordion div is large. so when i open that div/header. accordion goes beyond footer. How to set the height for accordion?

Comment: could u set up a fiddle??

Comment: use class `.ui-accordion`

Comment: do you want the height to be applied to a particular tab body or to the entire accordion

Comment: i'm having just 2 tabs so tab body or entire accordion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So try

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/46E6y/)

Comment: Thanks...it works...Would you tell me how to set height for tab bodies??

Comment: @HungryDB you can use the class `ui-tabs-panel`